# autocomplete data does not appear in bootstrap modal, but only the list appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I have a problem autocomplete the bootstrap modal. when I enter the keyword search for the book, but only black dots appear. any solution to this?
things that happen as you can see in the image, I've tried adding CSS z-index but the results are still the same.
[image]

```
public function CheckingBook()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        if ( isset($_GET['term']) ) {
            $result = $this->book_model->GetBookByTitle($_GET['term']);
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    
                    $data[] = array(
                        'judul_buku' => $row['judul_buku'],
                        'isbn_buku'  => $row['isbn_buku'],
                        'kode_buku'  => $row['kode_buku']
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $data = [
                    'msg' => 'error',
                    'gagal' => 'Tidak ada data yang ditemukan' 
                ];
            }
        } else {
            $data = [
                'msg' => 'error',
                'gagal' => 'Tidak ada data yang di inputkan' 
            ];
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Tidak punya akses langsung kehalaman tersebut');
        redirect(base_url('adminpage/book'),'refresh');
    }
}
```

this is jquery autocomplete

```
$('#bookTitleAdd').autocomplete({
    source: '/perpustakaan/adminpage/book/CheckingBook',
    select : function (event,ui) {
        $('#bookTitleAdd').val(ui.item.judul_buku)
        $('#bookISBNAdd').val(ui.item.isbn_buku)
    }
});

<input type="text" name="judulBuku" class="form-control" id="bookTitleAdd" placeholder="Judul Buku" autocomplete="off">
```

I try to look at the xhr network and then see the data objects in the array
[image]

Comment: It seems to a CSS problem. Please find out about the Autocomplete panel in the Inspect panel. Bootstrap autocomplete panel works the same way as modal.

Comment: I don't think it's in CSS. when I use Array data $ data [] = $ row-> judul_buku, the result will appear. but when I create an object in the array, only List appears. no book title were displayed. When I inspect the html element, the list exists but has no value

Comment: Autocomplete is expecting an Array of items or an array of Object with `{label, value}` pairs. You can have more keys, but it's looking for those two. I don't see that in your response. Also, you have an odd if statement that might redirect and this can cause issue with Autocomplete not getting results. I would send back an empty Array if there is an issue or an error. See: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: thanks, solved. in array added item label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
               $data[] = array(
                    'label' => $row['judul_buku'], //solved this
                    'judul_buku' => $row['judul_buku'],
                    'isbn_buku'  => $row['isbn_buku'],
                    'kode_buku'  => $row['kode_buku']
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It's because of z-index. Boostrap modal has z-index=1050. jquery-ui menu has z-index=100.

You can use this:

```
.ui-menu.ui-autocomplete.ui-front {
z-index: 1100;
```

}